# Prove E(x)=pn by taking derivative of Newtons binomial theroem

Tags: derivatives, binomial-theorem

I have this formula:

$E(X)=$$\sum_{k=1}^n k$$n \choose k$$p^k$$(1-p)^{n-k}$

and I am trying to prove $E=(X)=pn$, by taking the derivative of with respect to y:

$(x+y)^n=$$\sum_{k=0}^n$$n \choose k$$x^{n-k}$$y^k$

Heres what I got:

so first I am going to do a substituation:

$=$$\sum_{k=1}^n $k $n \choose k$$p^k$$(1-p)^{n-k}$

$k$$n \choose k$$=$$k *$ $\frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!}$$=n*$$\frac {(n-1)!} {(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$=n*$${n-1} \choose {k-1}$

Giving me this:

$=n$$\sum_{k=1}^n$ ${n-1} \choose {k-1}$ $p^k$ $(1-p)^{n-k}$

$=n$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}$ ${n-1} \choose {l}$ $p^{l+1}$ $(1-p)^{n-1-l}$

$=pn$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}$ ${n-1} \choose {l}$ $p^{l}$ $(1-p)^{n-1-l}$  (newton's formula)

$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}$ ${n-1} \choose {l}$ $p^{l}$ $(1-p)^{n-1-l}$ => 
$(x+y)^{n-1}$ $x=1-p; y=p$

thus,

we get $pn$

Comment: Also, note that you can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. That makes them a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You gave a correct argument using manipulation of binomial coefficients. Here is an argument using derivatives.

For any fixed $y$, let 
$$g(x)=(x+y)^n=\sum_0^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}.$$
Then
$$g'(x)=n(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_1^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}y^{n-k},$$
and therefore
$$xn(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_1^n k\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}.$$
Now put $x=p$ and $y=1-p$.

Comment: I am not sure why you started with 

$\sum_{k=0}^n$$n \choose k$$x^{k}$$y^{n-k}$. 

Newton's Binomial Theorem is $\sum_{k=0}^n$$n \choose k$$x^{n-k}$$y^k$

Comment: Same thing, interchange the roles of $n$ and $n-k$.  But if you prefer, rewrite the sum as $\sum \binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k$, look  at $(x+y)^n$, differentiate with respect to $y$, multiply by $y$, let $y=p$.

Comment: No rearranging, $p$ for one and $1-p$ for the other, sum $x+y$ is $1$, and $(x+y)^{n-1}=1$.